# Selenium: how to execute every element in a page

Tags: loops, selenium-webdriver

I want to use selenium to test every possible user actions in a web application. For example there are 2 paths in an application like `pageA->pageB->pageC->pageD; pageA->pageB->pageE` and we use a list to store the elements on `pageB`. I want to use a for loop to test every element in this list.

The problem is: after testing the first path, how to go back to `pageB` to execute another user action? Is this a method to record the state or position of `pageB` so that can go back to `pageB` then test the second element?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do is to test the real behavior of a user. So you can either create 2 tests, one for each path, or one test with the first path, then go back in the history using `Navigation.back` (or with navigation button provided by your website) and then go to page E.

The first solution is nice because you got 2 independent tests, the second is useful if you need to test some side effects of the first path.